# Share image on Facebook - iOS - Android

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator

I am developing an app for iOS and Android using Appcelerator Titanium 5.5.1GA, using the classic development, but I don't know how to share an image on Facebook and Twitter.

Is there a module for that or something ?
Any help will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.
SDK 5.5.1 GA
iOS, Android

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:
facebook call share("facebook", title, text, imagePath), and share("twitter", title, text, imagePath) for twitter.

Comment: Thanks Roselyn, and forgive me but, i dont understand where the method "share" is located, i can't find it in the Appcelerator documentation. Can you give me more information about how to call it ?